# Impute missing values using the available obs from the corresponding group using r

Tags: r

Hi I tried to impute missing values using the available values in a corresponding group. Please see the following data for an example.

```
dput(question)
structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2004L, 2005L, 
2006L, 2007L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L), Score = c(NA, 100L, NA, 95L, 
NA, NA, 88L)), .Names = c("Group", "Year", "Score"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

For the first NA score for group A in year 2004, I would like to use the available obs from the closest year in the same group (that is 100 for Group A year 2005);
For NA in group A year 2006, I would like to use the average of score from 2005 and 2007 in group A;
For NS in group B year 2006 and 2007, I would like to use the number in 2008 for group B.

Is it any r package for imputation that is applicable to my cases? or do you have any suggestion on such imputation?

Really appreciate

*Updated*
I amended PsyNeuroSci’s macro so that the distance will be calculated using Year. Sorry I did not know how to put the amended codes after PsyNeuroSci’s.

```
impute_nearest = function(dat, var0, var){
  for(i in 1:length(dat[,var])){
    if(is.na(dat[,var][i])){
      na.pos <<- dat[, var0][i]
      non.na.pos <<- dat[, var0][which(!is.na(dat[,var]))]
      distance <<- min(abs(na.pos-non.na.pos))

          dat[,var][i] = mean(c(dat[which(dat[, var0]==(na.pos+distance)),var], dat[which(dat[, var0]==(na.pos-distance)),var]), 
                              na.rm=T)
    }
  }
     return(dat)
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imputation in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114812/imputation-in-r)

Comment: I don't see the whole logic behind your imputation wishes. Just checking: If you have only one close value (within 1 year difference) in the same group you want NA to be assigned to that value; if you have two values you want the mean of those; if you have no value within one year you take the closest available?

Comment: logic for imputation: To use the obs from the closest year(S) in the same group to replace NA. In the 2nd case, since 2005 and 2007 are both 1 year apart from 2006 in group A (ie. both are nearest nearest neighbors), the average of obs in 2005 and 2007 used. In case 3, the closest year with available score for 2006 and 2007 in group B is the score in 2008, so the score in 2008 group B  will be assigned to both 2006 and 2007. Hope it is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Hi nograpes, would you please specify a little bit? Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that using a single value or the mean of only two to impute your missings is a good idea. Imagine you have a huge outlier in year 2010 and the 5 values before it are all NAs.

However, here is a working solution for your problem. I know it is probably not the most elegant way, but it works and with that I let others suggest better ways to do it.

Split up your data based on the Groups:

```
datA=dat[dat$Group=="A",]
datB=dat[dat$Group=="B",]
```

Here is a short function that takes the mean of the closet nonmissing values of the same distance around the missing value.

```
impute_nearest = function(dat, var){
   for(i in 1:length(dat[,var])){
      if(is.na(dat[,var][i])){
         na.pos = which(is.na(dat[,var]))
         non.na.pos = which(!is.na(dat[,var]))
         distance = abs(na.pos-non.na.pos)

         dat[,var][i] = mean(c(dat[,var][i+distance], dat[,var][i-distance]), 
         na.rm=T)
      }
   }
   return(dat)
}
```

Use as follows with **dat** being your dataframe and **var** the name of the variable you wish to impute in that df. Give the Variable as a character (e.g. "Score"). Here is an example for one of the subsets of your data:

```
impute_nearest(datB, "Score")
```

Comment: Hi PsyNeuroSci,Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Hi PsyNeuroSci,Thank you for the suggestion. But it seems to me that the distance is not calculated based on Year. For example, It I change the year of 2007 in Group A into 2008, the obs that suppose to be used for NA in Year 2006 should be 100 from year 2005 instead of the the mean score of 2005 and 2007.

Comment: True, there is a mistake in the code (Guess it was late yesterday:). I'll get to that later and will put the corrected version up. Thanks for the feedback!