# Why is there an Error in RTu[i, 1:Nu[i]] in my ChoiceRT_ddm function in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to do a ddm analysis with the choiceRT_ddm function in R.
My dataframe (called DDM) is composed of three columns (subjID, choice, RT) with 4320 observations for 54 participants (80 obs/participants). Some observations are missing (13 to be precise).

When I try with the following code:

```
output <- choiceRT_ddm(data = DDM, niter = 2000, 
                       nwarmup = 1000, nchain = 4, ncore = 4)
```

I have the following warning and error:

> The following lines of the data file have NAs in necessary columns:
> 1509, 1510, 1511, 1512, 1513, 1514, 1515, 1516, 1517, 1518, 1519,
> 1520, 1521 (total 13 lines) These rows are removed prior to modeling
> the data. Error in RTu[i, 1:Nu[i]] <- subj_data$rt[subj_data$choice ==
> 2] : the number of objects that must be replaced is not a multiple of
> the size of the replacement.

When I am trying to delete the NAs before, the same is happening:

```
DDM2 <- na.omit(DDM)
output <- choiceRT_ddm(data = DDM2, niter = 2000, 
                       nwarmup = 1000, nchain = 4, ncore = 4)
```

> Error in RTu[i, 1:Nu[i]] <- subj_data$rt[subj_data$choice == 2] : the
> number of objects that must be replaced is not a multiple of the size
> of the replacement.

I have verified: my R version, my Rstan version and my packages version are recent enough, thus the problem is not related to that.

Could it be because I don't have the same number of responses for each participant?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your error with a toy data set that had some NA values.

```
library(hBayesDM)

# fake data with NAs
df <- data.frame(subjID = rep(1:10, 20),
                 choice = sample(1:2, 20*10, replace = TRUE),
                 RT = sample(1:20, 20*10, replace = TRUE))

df$RT[df$RT[40:55]] <- NA
df$choice[df$choice[40:55]] <- NA

# running this code gave the same error described in the question
choiceRT_ddm(data = df, niter = 20, nwarmup = 10, nchain = 4, ncore = 3)
```

But the analysis runs after imputing the NA values with the mean.

```
# replace each NA value with the mean of that vector
df$RT[is.na(df$RT)] <- mean(df$RT, na.rm = T)
df$choice[is.na(df$choice)] <- mean(df$choice, na.rm = T)

choiceRT_ddm(data = df, niter = 20, nwarmup = 10, nchain = 4, ncore = 3)
```

**Take away:** It appears the NA values in your dataset need to be imputed. Maybe because `choiceRT_ddm()` expects each participant to have the same number of responses, but your NAs are confined to some of the participants? Here I imputed with the mean, but there are other [strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114887/5456906).

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this imputation !